# Installing Android-RSS as shared library into Eclipse project

Tags: android, eclipse, rss-reader

So I have downloaded
https://github.com/ahorn/android-rss

I then added a folder in my project tree. In "Build path" I then  used "link source".

However, it shows over 100 errors.

I am still new to Eclipse, Android etc. so I am probably missing something? It can't resolve types. I suspect this will be a general problem for me until I learn how to use .java source code libraries located in their own directories.

Anyone else using this the Android-rss library and have it "physical" placed outside project directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not the total expert but I think you need to use the "ADD External Jar" button in the linkpath Tab. That will include the Jar file as referenced Library. Also go to Order and Export and tick the library.